# Using Moq, why can't I raise and verify an event in my Windows Forms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, events, moq

I have a Windows Form app and in the Form_Load EventHandler it sets a checkbox's checkstate, which works fine when I run the app. But I also want a unit test to verify that the event sets the checkbox to match the database value as expected. However in my unit test the moq framework's `.Raise` does not appear to trigger the event as I cannot get any verify method at all to pass.

Here is the code:

IForm1

```
public interface IForm1
{
    event EventHandler Load; //Assuming this exposes the Form's normal Load event to Test code
    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e);
    DataSet LoadData();
    CheckState MyCheckboxValue{ get;  set; }
}
```

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IForm1
{
    public CheckState MyCheckboxValue
    {
        get => checkBox1.CheckState;
        set => checkBox1.CheckState = value;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = LoadData();

        checkBox1.CheckState = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IndicatorName"] == "Y" ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
    }

    public DataSet LoadData()
    {
        //Dumbing down real-world scenario of reading a value from database
        //For this demo code, lets dummy load 1 in-memory value
        var dt = new DataTable("");
        dt.Columns.Add("IndicatorName", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Y");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return ds;
    }
}
```

The Test

```
public class Form1Should
{
    [Fact]
    public void SetCheckboxCheckedWhenDatasetIndicatorIsY()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dt = new DataTable("");
        dt.Columns.Add("CheckState", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Y");

        DataSet m_ds = new DataSet();
        m_ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        var mockForm1 = new Mock<IForm1>();

        // Various attempts to do setups related to the event so verify tests below will work
        mockForm1.SetupAdd(m => m.Load += new System.EventHandler(mockForm1.Object.Form1_Load));
        mockForm1.Setup(x => x.Form1_Load(this, EventArgs.Empty)).Verifiable(); // I think Verifiable() is required to verify this method is called further below?
        mockForm1.Setup(x => x.LoadData()).Returns(m_ds);

        // Act 
        mockForm1.Raise(x => x.Load += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);

        //Assert - I can't get any of these to work:
        mockForm1.Verify(x => x.Form1_Load(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<EventArgs>()));
        mockForm1.Verify(x => x.LoadData());
        mockForm1.VerifyAdd(x => x.Load += It.IsAny<EventHandler>());
        mockForm1.VerifySet(x => x.MyCheckboxValue = CheckState.Checked, Times.Once);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does `.Raise` have no effect?

Comment: You are not testing the form implementation. You are trying to mock an interface and test that moq mocks the interface correctly. There is nothing actually being tested here other than the mocking library

Comment: This post is most likely a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi Can you suggest then what it is I need to do to test that the event sets the checkbox? I don't understand and I can't find a matching example to copy.

Comment: @GaryBarrett You are actually mixing the sut and mock, you cannot or should not mock sut as you are doing. If you want to test checkbox, instantiate `Form1` call `Form1_Load` and check the state of the `MyCheckboxValue`. Not sure if that is possible though maybe you have to redesign a bit and inject some dependencies...